# Variable from kubernetes yaml causes: Could not resolve placeholder 'ACTUATOR_PASSWORD' in value "${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}"

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, kubernetes

When I run my application from IntelliJ, I get a `warning / error` though application builds fine and runs all tests through, is this something that I should ignore, or can this be handled fixed?

Kubernetes secret is used to create a random password, therefor I have a placeholder for that particular variable.

```
2019-02-26 19:45:29.600  INFO 38918 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-02-26 19:45:29.684  WARN 38918 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'actuatorSecurity': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ACTUATOR_PASSWORD' in value "${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}"
2019-02-26 19:45:29.685  INFO 38918 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-02-26 19:45:29.685  INFO 38918 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-02-26 19:45:29.707  INFO 38918 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-02-26 19:45:29.713  INFO 38918 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

`qronicle-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: actuator
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
type: Opaque
data:
  actuator-password: {{ randAlphaNum 10 | b64enc | quote }}
....
- name: ACTUATOR_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: actuator
      key: actuator-password
```

`application.properties`

```
# spring boot actuator access control
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
security.user.actuator-username=admin
security.user.actuator-password=${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD}
```

`ACTUATOR_PASSWORD` is consumed here

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class ActuatorSecurity : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Value("\${security.user.actuator-username}")
    private val actuatorUsername: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.user.actuator-password}")
    private val actuatorPassword: String? = null

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually for secrets you will mount it outside of the deployment yaml.

Here you could run `kubectl create secret generic <secret_name> --from-literal <secret_key> ='<password>'` under the k8 context where the nodes are going to be running.

This will create a secret there and the deployment yaml you have above will map it to an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

this does the trick in the `application.properties` file

> security.user.password=${ACTUATOR_PASSWORD:admin123}

where `admin123` will be used if the env var is not provided